# Application architecture for Codeigniter - multiple domain, single codebase, multiple databases

Tags: architecture, codeigniter

I've developed a website with the idea of using a single codebase for multiple sites each with their own DB. Currently one is live, with many (up to 100) to follow.

My question is about the ideal, best-practice way of managing this kind of architecture (not necessarily the easiest or most realistic, but the ideal from which I can work back from).

For the codebase I have gone down the route of making the entire thing one install of codeigniter and associated code and all site related configuration is in a set of config files that pick up the host name and use that to define the site title, tracking code, css/js directories etc. This seems to be a good setup and I can see it working for a large number of sites of the same code.

For the databases, how would one manage multiple databases as the schema changes with development? Would you manually push changes to the databases as needed or use an automatic tool? There is a Rails like migrations plugin for Codeigniter [here](http://github.com/cloudmanic/codeignitor-migrations), that seems like it might be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article should show you exactly how to do it. It is really simple and works fine.

[How to: Multi-site CodeIgniter Setup](https://philsturgeon.uk/codeigniter/2009/06/22/How-to-Multi-site-CodeIgniter-Set-up/)

Comment: Hi Phil - yes, this is it - I read this about a month ago when I was setting it up and I think that is the way to go for the code, was a really helpful post, thank you. I think my main difficulty will be getting the db management correct. I expect the database schema to change as development progresses and want to make sure I have a solid process to manage the updates.

Comment: Use migrations to get the schema changes working nicely http://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-migrations

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar situation. I wanted to have several directories all running the same application but using different databases. Here's how I did it:

First I created some empty sub-directories. For this example we'll call them `/subdir_1`, `/subdir_2` and `/subdir_3`.

Within each of these directories I made a copy of the CodeIgniter index.php file and placed it in each directory. My file structure now looks something like:

```
/application
/system
/subdir_1
     index.php
/subdir_2
     index.php
/subdir_3
     index.php
```

This could also be accomplished with some .htaccess rules but that's a whole other story.

In each of the index.php files I've changed the `$system_path` and `$application_folder` variables to point to the `/application` and `/system` directories. For my particular case I changed my index.php file to:

```
/*
*---------------------------------------------------------------
* SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
*---------------------------------------------------------------
*
* This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
* Include the path if the folder is not in the same  directory
* as this file.
*
*/
    $system_path = "../system";

/*
*---------------------------------------------------------------
* APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
*---------------------------------------------------------------
*
* If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
* folder then the default one you can set its name here. The folder
* can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server.  If
* you do, use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide:
* http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
*
* NO TRAILING SLASH!
*
*/
    $application_folder = "../application";
```

At this point hitting any of the sub directories should display your application.

From here we need to set the `base_href` for each directory. We'll do this with a simple change to the main `/application/config/config.php` file. Replace the `$config['base_url']` line in your `/application/config/config.php` file with:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pieces = explode('/', $uri);

if ($pieces[1] == 'index.php') {
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    define('SITE', 'default');
} else {
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $pieces[1] . '/';
    define('SITE', $pieces[1]);
}
```

The above snippet sets the `$config['base_url']` to the appropriate sub directory (or the root directory if not in a sub-directory).

The `define('SITE', $pieces[1])` line creates a constant we can access throughout our application to let us know which sub-directory we're in.

The final piece of the puzzle it so let our application know which database to use. In my case I wanted each sub-directory to use its own database. To do this we'll use the `SITE` constant we created in the `config.php` file.

In our `/application/config/database.php` file we're going to add some alternate database settings. To do this we copy the `[default]` database connection settings and setup alternate settings for each of our subdomains. Here's how one of my sets look:

```
$db['subdir_1']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['subdir_1']['username'] = "[USERNAME]";
$db['subdir_1']['password'] = "[PASSWORD]";
$db['subdir_1']['database'] = "[DATABASE]";
$db['subdir_1']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['subdir_1']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['subdir_1']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['subdir_1']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['subdir_1']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['subdir_1']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['subdir_1']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['subdir_1']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['subdir_1']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['subdir_1']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['subdir_1']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I have other sets for `[subdir_2]` and `[subdir_3]`.  Now we need to tell our application which database settings to use. To do this we grab the `SITE` constant, so the final line in our `/application/config/database.php` file is:

```
$active_group = (defined('SITE') && array_key_exists(SITE, $db)) ? SITE : 'default';
```

The above line sets the active database settings group to match the sub directory.

And thats it :) Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: This setup will avoid having a master DB to log in the users from different databases and then associate them with their database. It's simpler and avoids unnecessary complications. It should work properly if the source code and the databases are on the same server. But it can work probably even when you'll need to scale up. You put the IP addresses of AWS instances for different databases (in config/databases.php) on the hostname, and configure the cloud accordingly. I mean on AWS db instances, opening the port 3306 and restricting the port to the source code server IP address.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you have multiple logical websites running off a single physical instance of the code, but each site has it's own database.

This is known as '[Multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy)'; and you should be able to find plenty of architectural advice for this.

I haven't done a lot of this myself, and it's definitely non-trivial.  It's a lot like security - you can't add it as an after-thought, if you want best practice you'll have to bake it into the design before you write a line of code.

It goes without saying that the code-base itself is only part of the overall solution: change management is going to be several orders of magnitude more difficult.

Sorry I can't offer more specific help.